# How to output the ID of the maximum average in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with data. I want to find the average by Criteria 1 for each Department ID (Department IDs are repeated) and output the value of the Department ID that has the maximum average. How can I do this? [I attach a table with data.]

| Department ID | Criteria 1 |
| --- | --- |
| DEP 001 | 4 |
| DEP 002 | 2 |
| DEP 003 | 1 |
| DEP 004 | 5 |
| DEP 001 | 3 |
| DEP 003 | 2 |
| DEP 002 | 4 |
| DEP 001 | 3 |
| DEP 004 | 2 |
| DEP 001 | 1 |
| DEP 002 | 3 |
| DEP 003 | 4 |

```
Average(DEP 001) = (4+3+3+1)/4 = 11/4 = 2.75

Average(DEP 002) = (2+4+3)/3 = 9/3 = 3

Average(DEP 003) = (1+2+4)/3 = 7/3 = 2.3

Average(DEP 004) = (5+2)/2 = 7/2 = 3.5

MAX(Average(DEP 001), Average(DEP 002), Average(DEP 003), Average(DEP 004)) = 3.5

Result = DEP 004
```

Comment: first check this [How to put tables in Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow)

Comment: then also add the excepted result for the sample data you've given...

Comment: why did you remove the other Criterias ? It changes the answer a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first let's create the average table

Modelling --> New Table

```
average table =
ADDCOLUMNS (
    SUMMARIZE ( YourTableName, YourTableName[Department ID ] ),
    "avg",
        CALCULATE (
            AVERAGE ( YourTableName[Criteria 1] ),
            ALLEXCEPT ( YourTableName, YourTableName[Department ID ] )
        )
)
```

then let's create the card which shows the max

```
Maximum Average =
VAR _max =
    MAX ( 'average table'[avg] )
RETURN
    LOOKUPVALUE ( 'average table'[Department ID ], 'average table'[avg], _max )
```

[image: result]

**but**, like your first post, if you have more than 1 criteria, you should unpivot and find a solution after the unpivoting ;)

Comment: I think this approach deviates quite a lot from best modeling practice - why persist a table in your data model just for this simple calculation?

Comment: @Marcus this is the best I can do )))

Answer (score 0):

Here is a measure that does this directly without adding bloat in your model:

```
ID of Max Avg = 
VAR _tbl =
    SUMMARIZE ( 
        'Table' , 
        'Table'[Department ID] ,
        "Avg" , AVERAGE ( 'Table'[Criteria 1] )
    )
VAR _top = 
    TOPN (
        1 ,
        _tbl , 
        [Avg] , 
        DESC
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
        SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Department ID] ) , 
        _top 
    )
```

Here the measure is used in a Card visual using your sample data:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
CALCULATE(
    SELECTEDVALUE(tbl[Department ID])
    ,FILTER(
        VALUES(tbl[Department ID])
        ,CALCULATE(AVERAGE(tbl[Criteria 1]))=MAXX(
                                            VALUES(tbl[Department ID])
                                            ,CALCULATE(Average(tbl[Criteria 1]))
                                        )
    )
)
```